# Automatically impl From<&T> after defining From<T>

Tags: rust

Consider the following MRE:

```rust
struct A {}
struct B {}

impl From<A> for B {
    fn from(t: A) -> B { B {} }
}
```

Is it possible to automatically implement `From<&A> for B`?

Comment: Sounds like you want `Clone`? That'd be the more conventional way to go from `&T`.

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically"?

Comment: make B: impl From<&A> without defining `from` twice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You will have to write it yourself.

```
impl From<&A> for B {
    fn from(a: &A) -> B {
        unimplemented!("implement me")
    }
}
```

The only *blanket implementation* for `From` is [`impl<T> From<T> for T`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html#impl-From%3CT%3E-12) (the identity conversion), there is no `#[derive]` macro available (used for other "automatic" implementations), and no other macro that I'm aware of exists (though you could probably make one without much fuss if you really wanted it).

Answer (score 0):

The direction you want is not possible. E.g. consider a struct `Str` which doesn't implement `Clone`, and `A=B=Str`. Then there is `impl From<A> for B` (that is, `impl From<Str> for <Str>`), but how could you write

```
fn from(t: &Str) -> Str
```

which you need for `impl From<&A> for B`?

It makes some sense going the other way: if you have an `impl From<&A> for B`, then you can easily define `impl From<A> for B`:

```
impl From<A> for B {
    fn from(t: A) -> B { From::from(&t) }
}
```

There is still no built-in way to do it (as kmdreko's reply says), but it's possible.

It also makes sense if you add a requirement that `A: Clone`.